# Unit testing with synchronous file operations

Tags: c#, unit-testing, file-io

### My problem:

I want to implement unit testing in my project which is heavily reliant on file operations, which involves ZIP extraction, file manipulation and validations and finally a new output file. I'm stuck on how best to implement it, as there is a synchronous chain of file operations currently in use.

---

### My scenario:

The basic sequence of the project is as follows:

1. Extract a ZIP file (which is associated with a class named `Batch`)
2. Load each extracted PDF file into a their own `Letter File` classes, which are then added as children to `Batch`
3. Run some checks across each `Letter File` to make sure it's valid and work out what type of `Letter File` it is (which is somewhat reliant on a folder structure as well). For example, I read the PDF to check for a certain string, which then changes how the file is handled.
4. Some of the files extracted are handled in a more complicated way, where they will be CSV files and I need to check files they reference actually exist after the ZIP has been extracted.
5. Finally, the batch is used to create a new CSV document referencing each letter.

---

### Where I'm stuck:

I've started doing unit tests by storing a test ZIP with two good `Letter Files` in my resources, and at the start of the unit test I run a method to create a temporary folder. I can test the file extracts correctly and produces two letter file outputs without too much of an issue.

The problem is that when I try and get to my next test, I need the previous files and classes to exist. I am pretty certain that unit tests should be able to exist independent of each other, so I'm trying to work out the best way to accomplish this.

---

### Things I've considered:

1. Calling methods to run through each stage of the operations for each test. By the last test, I'd have effectively ran every test multiple times by the last one.
2. Faking the processes by storing each element as resources and extracting them where they should be. I don't think this would properly test things though, and would be a nightmare to update if the main processes changed as I'd have to update all the tests to reflect this.
3. Somehow spoofing the file system..?

I've realised I may be doing too many operations actually on the file system where I *could* move them to being operations on the class instead. For example, I currently read the PDF, check if it has the string, then set an enum based on the result in the class. I think it may make more sense to store the string contents of the PDF in the class (even if only temporarily), then I can spoof that, and run the same comparisons. I'm not sure how I'd go about this with the example of checking files existed though.

---

### Summarised question:

How can I perform unit testing on classes that are heavily reliant on file references, especially where some results would rely on the output from previous tests/methods?

Comment: Tests which include I/O operations on files on disk are not unit but _integration tests_. Your scenario could be a single _end-to-end_ test but it could be broken down to multiple integration tests where each test has its own independent test-data.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Test has the concept of [*ordered tests*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx). BTW, MSDN documentation states:

> In an ordered test, each test is self-contained and independent. So
>   the environment state is not retained between each test that is run.

So it seems like ordering tests to have certain files and environment state from some previous test won't work with ordered tests.

Anyway, you should be able to output the required files for each next test (in order) in some known place in the machine where your test are being executed, and since your tests are executed in order you have full guarantee that each test will work as expected.